# default id in ArrayDataProvider

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

When i use

```
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

and then use this dataprovider in gridview and get selected rows in action like this

```
   if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
   $selectedUser = $_POST['selection'];
   }
```

It works fine and i have array of selected user's id like this Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 7 )  where 5 and 7 are user's ids.

But when i use some condition in $dataprovider like this 
for example

```
$modelUser = User::find()
        ->where(['class' => $model->class_id])
        ->all();
    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $modelUser,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50,
        ],
    ]);
```

And then use this provider in gridview, now in action when i use

```
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
  $selectedUsers = $_POST['selection'];
  }
```

It gives array like this  Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 )
meant to say it doesn't give user's ids. I need selected user's ids.

Comment: `$POST['selection']` is changed to something else view generated html and find exact name or id for posted data.

Comment: Please give your view code

Comment: <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

            'id',

            [
                'attribute' => 'user_id',
                'label' => 'User',
                'value' => 'user.first_name',

            ],
     ],
    ]); ?>

Comment: There are more attributes but i just write only one here

Comment: it will give you selected **serialColumn** . First see what `Yii::$app->request->post()` contains.

Comment: @InsaneSkull But i'm using ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'] in gridview

Comment: anyway yii::$app->request->post() showing


Array ( [_backendCsrf] => OEdTSVBsenlofhI3Fh76K3lqCx0kVUk3GHUyPewvCRZNCx4aGi8wQA== [Attendance] => Array ( [status] => ) [selection_all] => 1 [EnrollmentSearch] => Array ( [id] => [user_id] => [stdclass_id] => [session_id] => ) [selection] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved myself. Just add a key in array dataprovider

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $modelUser,
    'Key' => 'id',
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 50,
    ],
]);
```